# Google play console message: Newly supported devices is zero (0)

Tags: android

I want to release a new update for my app but in google play console it display 0 in Newly supported device, I don't use any feature in my app! is it important at all?

this is google play console:
[image]

(devices no longer support is for increasing minimum sdk)

this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ir.kolbe.fale_ghahve">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/fortuneteller"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/fortuneteller_round"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".settingActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".TarootActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".sheikh.showJadvalAuto" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <service android:name=".Utils.BackgroundSoundService" />
    <!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-7990391538461789~6976996140"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

and this is my dependencies in build.gradle:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, it is newly supported device, not supported device it just says no new device is supported with last update but old ones are still in support